# Consulta MYSQL nombre del producto más caro que tiene cada fabricante y su precio

Tags: mysql, sql

Devuelve un listado con el nombre del producto más caro que tiene cada fabricante. El resultado debe tener tres columnas: nombre del producto, precio y nombre del fabricante. El resultado tiene que estar ordenado alfabéticamente de menor a mayor por el nombre del fabricante.

Base de datos:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tienda;
CREATE DATABASE tienda CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
USE tienda;

CREATE TABLE fabricante (
  codigo INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE producto (
  codigo INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  precio DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  codigo_fabricante INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (codigo_fabricante) REFERENCES fabricante(codigo)
);

INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(1, 'Asus');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(2, 'Lenovo');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(3, 'Hewlett-Packard');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(4, 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(5, 'Seagate');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(6, 'Crucial');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(7, 'Gigabyte');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(8, 'Huawei');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(9, 'Xiaomi');

INSERT INTO producto VALUES(1, 'Disco duro SATA3 1TB', 86.99, 5);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(2, 'Memoria RAM DDR4 8GB', 120, 6);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(3, 'Disco SSD 1 TB', 150.99, 4);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(4, 'GeForce GTX 1050Ti', 185, 7);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(5, 'GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme', 755, 6);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(6, 'Monitor 24 LED Full HD', 202, 1);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(7, 'Monitor 27 LED Full HD', 245.99, 1);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(8, 'Portátil Yoga 520', 559, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(9, 'Portátil Ideapd 320', 444, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(10, 'Impresora HP Deskjet 3720', 59.99, 3);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(11, 'Impresora HP Laserjet Pro M26nw', 180, 3);
```

Esta es la consulta que estoy tratando de hacer

```
SELECT p.nombre as 'nombre del producto más caro', MAX(p.precio) as 'precio del producto', f.nombre as 'nombre del fabricante'
FROM fabricante f LEFT JOIN producto p ON f.codigo = p.codigo_fabricante
GROUP BY f.nombre
ORDER BY f.nombre;
```

El problema que tengo con esta consulta es que el nombre del producto no se corresponde con la columna del precio, las columnas de precio del producto y nombre de fabricante si las muestra bien  he intentado hacer varías subconsultas pero no consigo resolverlo.

Comment: Si el resultado tiene que estar ordenado por el nombre del fabricante, porque estas ordenando por el nombre mas el precio.

Comment: Lo acabo de corregir, no se ni yo mismo porque lo ordene así la verdad estoy desesperado con esta consulta.

Comment: @Dazai_red dime si te funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dazai, me imagino que lo que buscas es lo siguiente, con una consulta directamente. A ver si te vale...

```
SELECT 
  fab.nombre,
  maximos.nombre,
  maximos.precio 
FROM
  producto maximos 
  LEFT JOIN producto mayores 
    ON maximos.codigo_fabricante = mayores.codigo_fabricante 
    AND maximos.precio < mayores.precio 
  JOIN fabricante fab 
    ON maximos.codigo_fabricante = fab.codigo 
WHERE mayores.precio IS NULL 
ORDER BY fab.nombre ASC
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido

Answer (score 1):

### Lo puedes solucionar de 2 formas :

#### La primera forma :

```
SELECT producto.nombre, producto.precio, fabricante.nombre
FROM fabricante,producto WHERE producto.codigo = fabricante.codigo
ORDER BY fabricante.nombre ASC, producto.precio;
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/287)

#### La segunda forma y es como tu pones en tu código :

```
SELECT p.nombre as 'nombre del producto más caro', p.precio as 'precio del producto', f.nombre as 'nombre del fabricante'
FROM fabricante f LEFT JOIN producto p ON f.codigo = p.codigo_fabricante
ORDER BY f.nombre, p.precio DESC;
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/289)

Comment: Gracias por intentar ayudarme, he probado las dos consultas pero no me devuelve lo que pretendo que es el el producto con mayor precio que tiene cada fabricante, en tu respuesta me devuelve productos con su fabricante pero no el que tiene mayor precio

Comment: Se puede hacer pero con un procedimiento si quieres lo modifico y te lo coloco, como tu lo prefieras @Dazai_red

Comment: si, gracias de antemano

Comment: vale ahora me pongo con el procedimiento

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funcionó de esta manera:

````
```
select f.nombre, max(p.precio), max(CASE WHEN p.precio = p.precio THEN 
p.nombre else null end)
from producto p left join fabricante f  on p.codigo_fabricante = f.codigo 
group by f.nombre order by f.nombre asc;```
````

Comment: No olvides explicar qué hace la consulta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Por cierto, los triples acentos graves (```) van una línea antes y una después del código.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funcionó de esta manera:

```
select producto.nombre as nombre, max(producto.precio) as precio, fabricante.nombre as fabricante
from tienda.producto
inner join tienda.fabricante
on fabricante.id = producto.id_fabricante
group by nombre, fabricante having precio = any(select max(producto.precio) from tienda.producto group by id_fabricante) order by fabricante asc
```

La siguiente consulta realiza un inner join entre las tablas fabricante y producto agrupando por nombre de producto y fabricante, para seleccionar el precio mayor de cada producto para cada fabricante realice una subconsulta usando el operador any que evalúa si alguno de los precios
cumple la condicion de que su precio exista en la tabla de la subconsulta.

la subconsulta me devuelve el precio mas caro de cada producto agrupando dicho precio por el id del fabricante.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
select f.nombre,tt.nombre,tt.precio
from fabricante as f inner join (select p.nombre,t.fabricante,t.precio
from producto as p inner join (select id_fabricante as 
fabricante,max(precio) as precio
                            from producto
                            group by id_fabricante) as t
on p.id_fabricante = t.fabricante and p.precio = t.precio) as tt
on f.id = tt.fabricante
```

order by f.nombre;

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).